# express-http-proxy is not passing req.user in proxied service nodejs

Tags: node.js, http-proxy, express-http-proxy

In nodejs created a gateway that proxies the apis based on some conditions. The gateway also checks the headers in token and if validated then set the `req.user`

Here is the proxy code

```
proxy(host) {
        // call proxy middleware with request option  
        return (req, res, next) => {
            let reqBodyEncoding;
            let reqAsBuffer = false;
            let parseReqBody = true;
             
            return default_proxy(host, {
                reqAsBuffer,
                reqBodyEncoding,
                parseReqBody,
            })(req, res, next);
        }
    }
```

now on my proxied service I am not getting `req.user`. What is the solution for this?

Comment: You must pass `req.user` in the request to the target host somehow. The target host gets a fresh `req` object (assuming it is implemented in Node.js at all), therefore it cannot see the gateway's `req` object. You could, for example, set a request header `X-User: <value of req.user>`, but then you must authenticate the request so that the target host can be sure it was made by the gateway (and not by someone who wants to impersonate the user).

Comment: any way if i can pass the user as req.user and what is the best practice?

Comment: I don't understand: The gateway makes an HTTP request to the target host, not a Javascript call. Therefore you cannot pass on the `req` object.

Comment: yes to my another api server, like it is passing everything headers and body. so i thouht my custom object will be passed to o set on req

Comment: The other api server gets a fresh `req` object, nothing is passed on. That's how express works.